# How to take action if ZeroMQ doesn't receive messages?

Tags: python, zeromq

I've got some sort of distributed control system in which I send a heart beat every second. On the receiving end I need to take action if no message has been received for more than 2 seconds. The problem is that when zeroMQ is waiting for an answer I can't do anything else, like checking how much time has passed since the last message was received.

The code I have now is below. Does anybody know how I could take action if no message has been received for more than 2 seconds? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT] With the tip of Pieter Hintjes I added polling to the code, but I still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

```
from datetime import datetime
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()

# Set up subscriber connection to receive message from broker
subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.connect('tcp://localhost:8888')
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'beat')

# Initialise poll set
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(subscriber, zmq.POLLIN)

while True:
    socks = dict(poller.poll(2000))
    if subscriber in socks and socks[subscriber] == zmq.POLLIN:
        message = subscriber.recv()
        print(message)

    print('do other stuff')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use poll on the ZMQ socket instead of a blocking recv. There are lots of examples of this in the ZeroMQ Guide.

Comment: Pieter Hintjes - Dankje! I think you are right that I need to use poller. The thing is that I still don't know how to set an action if it hasn't received data for two seconds. I updated the code in my initial post to how I try it now. Would you possibly have any other tip or hint(je)?